# Rectangle overlapping outside the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, canvas

I am creating a rectangle inside a canvas. I am using the div width as the width of the rectangle. The rectangle from the left side is going above the canvas container. I want to keep the canvas inside the container and width equal to the width of div.

Here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvasReference = canvasRef.current;
    const divReference = divRef.current;
    const context = canvasReference?.getContext("2d");
    if (context && divReference) {
      context.strokeStyle = "#000";
      context.strokeRect(0, 0, divReference.clientWidth, 45);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={divRef}>
      <canvas className="timelineCanvas" ref={canvasRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-opu2nu)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set canvas width and height in you css file, and also instead of using divReference.clientWidth you should use divReference.offsetWidth because it also contains border size ;)